# Oracle UUID v3 or v5

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to create UUID v3 or v5 on the fly from selected data for getting UUID, which is made from the username and constant "Name space". I don't want to generate and save this data in the DB, only just get it on demand

For example something like this:

```
SELECT uuid('NAME SPACE', a.username) uuid  
FROM USER_TABLE a 
where a.username = 'username';
```

I'm using Oracle 19c

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that in SQL itself Oracle only had the `SYS_GUID` and it is not v3 or v5. `SYS_GUID` is globally unique, but not compliant to RFC 4122.